# How can you initialize an object from a variables value?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I would like to generate the name of a soon to be initialized object by getting the user input. Is this possible? Is there a way to name an object based on a variables value?

I know in the code below the "test x" doesn't work and I know why... but is there a way to get this to work? I have been trying to figure it out for 2 days now. The closest thing I came to was maybe stringstreams... or even worse... it isn't possible? Any help?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <string>

class test
{
public:
    string wtf;
};

int main()
{
    test y;         // showing normal initialize
    y.wtf = "a";    // assign value


    string x;       
    cin >> x;       // initialize string and get input

    test x          // trying to initialize object based on input
    x.wtf = "a";    // then assign a value


    cout << y.wtf;  // printing both to test
    cout << x.wtf;

    return 0;
}
```

My intent is to have a single array that holds employee numbers (concatenated with a an "emp" or something in the beginning) to initiate objects for each employee. So the user would input an employee number, say 1234, and I would make a string that added emp + 1234 and come out with "emp1234"... which I would then initiate an object like "test emp1234" which would have a bunch of difference variables associated with it, inside the class.

I may be looking at this all wrong... and probably explained it fairly crappy. I am obviously new to this, but I could use any help possible.

Comment: I think you're looking for [std::map](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/)

Comment: I have looked at that the other night and again right now... but I can't see how that would work in my scenario. Perhaps I don't truly understand it's working, but I need to store a value in an array and then call a specific position of the array to either set or get values of a class. So I would need essentially the ability to call "array[0].wtf" and "array[2].wtf"

I see how the std::map would allow for the creation of an object initially, but I don't understand how it would be called again.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>

test make_test()
{
    std::string s;
    if (!(std::cin >> s))
    {
        throw std::runtime_error("Premature end of input");
    }
    return { "emp" + s };
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<test> v;

    for (int i = 0; i != 10; ++i)
    {
         v.push_back(make_test());
         std::cout << "Added employee '" << v.back().wtf << "'\n";
    }
}
```

This would fill a vector with ten employee records.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't create variable names at run-time simply because names do not exist at run-time. They are static constructs that are only useful during compilation.

However, it really sounds like you just want a `std::map`. You can use this to map from integers (employee number) to an `test` object:

```
std::map<int, test> employees;

int employeeNumber;
std::cin >> employeeNumber;

employees[employeeNumber]; // Will default construct a test object mapped to employeeNumber

// Alternatively:
test t( /* some constructor args */ );
employees[employeeNumber] = t;
```

Then, if you want to access the `test` object with employee number `1234`, for example, you could simply do:

```
employees[1234]
```

Comment: How would that handle multiple data members of an object though, without making a huge array to store everything. I would like to take the user input and assign multiple values to it... so I would have 
"x.wtf" and "x.wtf2" and so on. I think my biggest issue here is trying to get my point across. I will look into the map idea, but I don't think it is what I need.